# Rust macros: match argument as closure but differentiate between non-closure-expression and closure-expressions

Tags: rust, macros

I want to create a macro that can be used like this

```
    generate_code!(println!("macro argument is expression"));
    generate_code!(|| println!("macro argument is closure"));
```

Unfortunately both macro arguments match as "expr". My macro should be smart enough to add `||` in the first case. Is this possible in Rust?

```
macro_rules! generate_code {
    // for `generate_code!(println!())`
    ($expression:expr) => {do_sth(|| $expression)};

    // for `generate_code!(|| println!())`
    ($closure:expr???) => {do_sth($closure)};
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can match the closure tokens explicitly:

```
macro_rules! generate_code {
    (|| $expression:expr) => {do_sth(|| $expression)};
    (move || $expression:expr) => {do_sth(move || $expression)};
    ($expression:expr) => {do_sth(|| $expression)};
}
```

(I've included the `move` closures as well, which are often used.)

For example, this runs as expected:

```
fn do_sth(f: impl FnOnce()) {
    f();
}

fn main() {
    generate_code!(println!("macro argument is expression"));
    generate_code!(|| println!("macro argument is closure"));
    generate_code!(move || println!("macro argument is move closure"));
}
```

Note that this approach could lead to surprising results because it doesn't *really* detect closures, it just detects the literal `||` token sequence. If you disguise a closure as `generate_code!((|| println!("xxx")))` or if the closure takes arguments, as `generate_code!(|foo| println!("{}", foo))`, the expression will be treated as a non-closure expression and will be stuffed in the closure. Depending on the bounds on type accepted by `do_sth`, the result be either a cryptic compilation error such as "expecting unit type, found closure" or (worse) successful compilation and unwanted behavior.